# ASP.NET GridView update Source but not commands

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview, filtering

I have a gridview. Its datasource is taken from XML by adding some xmlElemens in a list and than set the list as its data source. Now I am implementing a search feature.

So I am filtering the list in this way:

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(prog); //Percorso file xml

        List<string> nomi = new List<string>();

        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNodeList elemLists = root.GetElementsByTagName("nome");
        // this binds the gridview to the title text to display
        for (int i = 0; i < elemLists.Count; i++)
        {
            if(elemLists[i].InnerXml.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(txtSearchMaster.Text.ToLower()) || 
                elemLists[i].InnerXml.ToString().ToLower() == txtSearchMaster.Text.ToLower() ||
                elemLists[i].InnerXml.ToString().ToLower().EndsWith(txtSearchMaster.Text.ToLower()) ||
                elemLists[i].InnerXml.ToString().ToLower().Contains(txtSearchMaster.Text.ToLower()))

                nomi.Add(elemLists[i].InnerXml.ToString());
        }


        GridView1.DataSource = nomi.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

The data is shown correctly but the problem is that when I click the button next the column that is auto generated and get the cell content (that is an element of the list) it return the content of the cell at the same index but of the previous data.

How can I overcome to this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your "filter" as it were is only applied on the search click.  If you had hidden state where a search term was stored, and applied it on *every* postback, if the state exists, then clicking your grid button would work.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="SearchString" runat="server" value="" />
```

and in your btnSearch_Click

```
SearchString.Value = txtSearchMaster.Text.ToLower().Trim();
```

and then add the filter logic in Page_Load

```
if (IsPostBack) {
   // filter on hidden value if not empty.
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString.Value)) {
       // filter here
   }
}
```

Comment: so i have to store the search field and then refresh the page and filter after that? Is there a way without any refreshing?

Comment: The grid *is* refreshing the page upon the command execution (and doing html replacement). This is making sure that when the grid refreshes the page, it has the same results as prior.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed by adding

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{   
   ...
}
```

in Page_Load and leaving the filter login into the search button click method.

Comment: It seems that [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203936/296861) basically answered your question. Please help the community by accepting his answer rather than creating your own.

Comment: @Win well, actually he said a different thing. I would accept his answer if it would fix my problem but it did not. So, rather than to accept his non working answer I write the one I found for the next people that will come on this problem.

Comment: I see. If you want, you could propose him to alter his answer or lead him to correct solution. Anyhow, I'm glad that you figured out the issue.

Comment: I believe my answer would work, there might be one thing wrong with it, but I don't know because I don't have the advantage of being in front of his code.  I believe Alfred's works because the Grid has ViewState, and not populating the grid on Postback is also a valid solution.  But if the "Postback" cue led him to the answer it should be marked as helpful but not accepted.  I think that's the balance here.